# Computing two Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(2-z)(z+3)}$, centered at $z = 0$ and centered at $z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{1}{(2-z)(z+3)}$ centered at, first the origin ($z = 0$) and then another point ($z = 2$) for example.

First, the origin.  I notice that the origin ($z = 0$) lies between both of my singularities.  My biggest issue is figuring out the annulus of convergence.  I believe it should just be a disk of radius 2, since that's what it takes to reach the singularity at $z = 2$.  Is that right?  That's not really an annulus.

Second, considering the point $z = 2$, my annulus should be a disk centered at $z = 2$ with radius 5, since that's what it takes to get to the other singularity.  Somehow I don't think this is right.

Can somebody please point me in the right direciton?

Comment: At $z=0$, there are three possible Laurent series: One of them converges in your disk $\{|z|<2\}$ (this is the same as the power series of $f(z)$ at $z=0$); another one converges in the annulus $\{2<|z|<3\}$; and the third one converges in the circle-complement $\{|z|>3\}$. At $z=2$, there are two possible Laurent series: One of them converges in the punctured disk $\{0<|z-2|<5\}$; the other one converges in the circle-complement $\{|z-2|>3\}$. As a simpler example, consider the two Laurent series $\frac1{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ and $\frac1{1-z} = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} z^n$.

Comment: For $z=0$, you don't get an annulus, since there's no singularity at $z=0$ (or, if you prefer, you get a "degenerate" annulus).